# .NET: When is InputLanguageManager.Current null?

Tags: .net, input-language

We are using the following code to set the input language on the operating system:

```
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = initialCulture;
```

It works on development pc, but on production pc **Current** is null.

InputLanguageManager.Current is implemented as follows:

```
public static InputLanguageManager Current
{
  get
  {
    if (InputMethod.Current.InputLanguageManager == null)
      InputMethod.Current.InputLanguageManager = new InputLanguageManager();
    return InputMethod.Current.InputLanguageManager;
  }
}
```

InputMethod.Current is implemented as follows:

```
public static InputMethod Current
{
  get
  {
    InputMethod inputMethod = (InputMethod) null;
    Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread);
    if (dispatcher != null)
    {
      inputMethod = dispatcher.InputMethod as InputMethod;
      if (inputMethod == null)
      {
        inputMethod = new InputMethod();
        dispatcher.InputMethod = (object) inputMethod;
      }
    }
    return inputMethod;
  }
}
```

MSDN says InputMethod can be **null, when there is no active input method**.

I dont understand that. Does anyone else?

Comment: Facing the smae issue, did you solve it?